# python sql where using dates

Tags: python, sql, datetime, sqlite

I am trying to get all records that are within the current week(monday to sunday) and then I was planning to insert them back into the database but with the date of lesson being increased by 7. However I get the following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ">=": syntax error
```

I may be wrong but I think that this is due to how python stores dates is there a way around this, if not I can always get all records in table into array and filter that array in python. The code for the sql is underneath:

```
with sqlite3.connect("GuitarLessons.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        sql = "select *"\
              "from tblBookings"\
              "where DateOfLesson >=  ?"\
              "and DateOfLesson <= ?"
        cursor.execute(sql,(startweekd,endweekd))
        BookingList = cursor.fetchall()
        print(BookingList)
```

The rest of my code is just calculating the start and end date for that week.

```
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
import sqlite3

tdate = datetime.datetime.today()
tday = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()
tdadd = 7 - (tday+1)
endweekd = date.today() + timedelta(days=tdadd)
startweekd = endweekd - timedelta(days=7)
endweekd = endweekd.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
startweekd = startweekd.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
print(startweekd)
print(endweekd)
```

Comment: How are the dates stored in the table? Can you show some rows, preferably using the command-line client, so we know what is actually stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite (nowhere, not just in Python) does **not support dates**.

So you have to convert the dates, on query, but **also on storage**, to some format it will understand. There are two options:

- Number of seconds since some epoch, e.g. unix time, possibly fractional.
- Strings.

To make comparison of strings work, the dates **must** be stored in the **ISO 8601** format (or at least that order). ISO 8601 timestamp has format specification `"%FT%T"` (or on systems that don't understand `%F` or `%T` `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"`). Or just dates as `"%F"`/`"%Y-%m-%d"`. You can use different separators, but the only thing that will gain you is some confusion. Also SQLite has some built-in functions to work with date in ISO 8601 format.

I believe you can define the conversion somewhere so it will then be used automatically when binding query parameters, but I don't remember where. Manually is guaranteed to work.

Comment: okay so I need to first go through my database and change my dates and then come back to my code and put the dates in that format. Is there anything else I would need to do?(asking instead of doing right now as got lesson so don't have time)

Comment: @user2711309, I can't think of anything critical. Just keep in mind that SQLite is dynamically typed like python, so the entries you insert will be of the type you bind even if the schema says something else. And watch out for the automatic transactions in the python binding.

Answer (score 1):

`sqllite` requires date to be in `YYYY:MM:DD` format. You probably should use `strftime` with the following parameters:

```
endweekd   = endweekd.strftime("%Y:%m:%d")
startweekd = startweekd.strftime("%Y:%m:%d")
```

Comment: The SQLite functions for date manipulation expect `-`, not `:` between date components as per ISO 8601.